# How can I stop getting an invalid date in IE with moment.js?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, momentjs

This always returns "invalid date". It works in Chrome and Safari, but in IE I always get an invalid date.

The code in question:

```
  var utcMoment = moment.utc(value.Timestamp);
```

`value.Timestamp` is in this format: "17 Sep 15  19:55:37"

Should I be using a different date format? I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Is there any chance you could use four-digit years?

Comment: provide the format argument to moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can explicitly define the format when creating the moment.

```js
var utcMoment = moment.utc("17 Sep 15 19:55:37", "DD MMM YY HH:mm:ss");
console.log(utcMoment);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.js"></script>
```