# ChartJS extends years for 50 year in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, momentjs, internet-explorer-11

I have the following ChartJS graph in Chrome that uses moment.js for datetime formatting on the X axis.

[image]

but in EI 11 it looks like this. I cant understand why the years in IE are from 1970 till now but in chrome it plots the data fine.

[image]

Is this a formatting issue with moment.js?

Below is the code for creating the chart

```
if (data !== null) {
            $('#_LblAnalysisOverviewChartSaving').css('visibility', 'visible');
            var titleLabel = document.getElementById("LblChartTitleAuctionOverview").lastChild.nodeValue;
            var costLabel = document.getElementById("LblChartCost").lastChild.nodeValue;
            var timeLabel = document.getElementById("LblChartTime").lastChild.nodeValue;

            var dataLines = [];
            var dataLabels = [];
            var xvalues = [];
            // fill lines and labes array
            $.each(data, function (entryindex, entry) {
                dataLines.push(entry['PlotData']);
                dataLabels.push({ label: entry['Label'] });
            });

            // fill x axes values array with strings
            $.each(dataLines, function (index, value) {
                $.each(value, function (index1, value2) {
                    xvalues.push(value2[0]);
                });
            });
            // at this point xvalues is a array containing strings
            // in the form of 10/19/2020 15:50:20   -- (mm/dd/y h:m:s)


            function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
                return self.indexOf(value) === index;
            }
            // get only unique values for the x axes 
            var unique = xvalues.filter(onlyUnique);
            var momentsArray = [];

            //create moments array 
            $.each(unique, function (index, value) {
                momentsArray.push(moment.utc(value, "DD MMM YY HH:mm:ss"));
            });

            var ctxr = $('#OverviewChart');
            var myChart = new Chart(ctxr, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: momentsArray
                },
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    responsiveAnimationDuration: 1,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    aspectRatio: 1,
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: titleLabel
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        mode: 'index',
                        intersect: true
                    },
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                // Include a currency in the ticks
                                callback: function (value, index, values) {
                                    return curr + value;
                                }
                            },
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: costLabel
                            }
                        }],
                        xAxes: [{
                            type: 'time',
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: timeLabel
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });

            var borderColorsArr = ['rgba(196, 217, 45, 1)', 'rgba(75, 178, 197, 1)'];
            for (let i = 0; i < dataLines.length; i++) {
                var temp = dataLines[i].sort();
                tempArray = []
                for (var x = 0; x < temp.length; x++) {
                    var oneArray = temp[x];
                    for (var ix = 1; ix < oneArray.length; ix++) {
                        var object = {
                            x: oneArray[0],
                            y: oneArray[1],
                        }
                        tempArray.push(object)
                    }
                }
                myChart.data.datasets.push({
                    label: dataLabels[i].label,
                    data: tempArray,
                    borderColor: borderColorsArr[i]
                })
                myChart.update()
            }
        }
```

After all original comments I redid how the values for the x axes are filled.
but I still get exactly the same result. I hope from my comments around the code it is much more clear how the x axes values are generated and formatted.

Comment: It's not clear from what you posted, but it's very likely that the problem stems from the format of the dates involved. Different browsers tolerate different date formats, other than the standard ISO format. If your dates start off as strings, you should post what they look like.

Comment: Please look at the the comment below the definition of datetimeArrayDistinct  to see how the date time object looks at that point

Comment: @UncleDaveIsWatching that is a non-standard Date format. You can use Moment with **explicit** format instructions to ensure that it's correctly interpreted, or you can switch to using ISO standard date strings.

Comment: @UncleDaveIsWatching "At this point" suggest the value might be taken from the debugger. Are they `Date` objects or strings? Some debuggers cast the object to a string to make it more readable.

Comment: I agree with Pointy's opinion. Some date formats are invalid for IE. It's also said in [moment.js doc](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/known-formats/): *If you know the format of the date string that you will be parsing, it is always the best choice to explicitly specify that format.* You can also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660040/how-can-i-stop-getting-an-invalid-date-in-ie-with-moment-js) for more information.

Comment: I have made changes to the code to format the strings and make them into moments.js objects but unfortunately i still get the same output.

Comment: @UncleDaveIsWatching I've added a new answer, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the corresponding format to explicit. For example, you use date format `10/19/2020 15:50:20`, then it should be:

```
momentsArray.push(moment(value, "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss"));
```

Besides, it also may be related with the Chart.js version.

I made an example with **Chart.js 2.8.0** with **right date format** and it works fine on IE 11 and Chrome, you can refer to it:

```js
var xvalues = ["10/19/2020 15:50:20", "10/19/2020 15:50:21", "10/19/2020 15:50:22"];

function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

var unique = xvalues.filter(onlyUnique);
var momentsArray = [];

$.each(unique, function(index, value) {
  momentsArray.push(moment(value, "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss"));
});

var ctxr = $('#OverviewChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctxr, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: momentsArray
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Time'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="OverviewChart"></canvas>
```

Result in IE 11:
[image]